# It is possible to add values to an inline style using interpolation in Angular 4

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I'm learning angular 4 by myself, and I want to know if is it possible to do this:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-
valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width {{ item.percent_position}}%;">
{{ item.percent_position }}</div>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve is to extend the width in relation to the value thrown by **{{item.percent_position}}**

When I use **[style]="width: {{ item.percent_position }}%;"** I got this error: 
*Uncaught Error: Quotes are not supported for evaluation!
        Statement: {{item.percent_position}}%;*

What I want is this: [image: progress bar at 58%]

The result I get with the code above is this:
[image]

Comment: Use the `[style]` binding or `[NgStyle]`

Comment: like <div [style.width]="item.percent_position">

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you use square brackets, you're binding to an expression, so you're suggested solution doesn't work, as Angular expects this to be executable JS:

```
 [style]="width: {{ item.percent_position }}%;"
```

In contrast, the following should work perfectly fine:

```
 [style.width]="item.percent_position + '%' "
```

If you have multiple styles to bind to, you can use ngStyle to bind to an object:

```
 [ngStyle]="{ 'width': item.percent_position + '%' }"
```

In any case: If you use square brackets, make sure what is bound to it is an executable expression!

Comment: how to add two in line class (position:absolute) and (top:value)

Answer (score 2):

I found that style would not work, however, I could add a custom class and call that class. For example:

```
<div class="{{ item.className }}">
```

Hopefully, that helps someone who reads this page.

Answer (score 1):

> you can use [ngStyle] in place of style.
>   `<div [ngStyle]="{'width':cointinerWidth}"></span>`

Answer (score 0):

[ngStyle]="{'background': variable}"

Like I used in case of a  tag

test

and where color is a component provided variable.